# Purpose of "nil' at the end of Initializing Array in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, initialization

I have seen and done initialization of arrays and all put "nil" at the end of initialization but never question, why it is required to put there?

Plus if you are initializing your array in a loop, is it still necessary to put nil at the end of array? for example.

```
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++)
{
   [array addObject:@"1"];
}

// now this line is required or not after i exit the loop?
[array addObject:nil];
```

Comment: Out of interest, what has led you to believe it might be required?

Comment: @JeremyP - My app was crashing, so just thought, may that is causing the crash. Though i was wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This concept is called **nil-termination**, and it's purpose is to provide a **sentinel** to the receiving function or method of where the variable argument list ends.

Comment: But should I put it in the given example? I have just experiment with that and it seems to crash my app.

Comment: @itsaboutcode, No, this is only necessary with the variadic convenience methods.

Comment: In fact, [array addObject:nil] will crash since you can't put nils in NSArrays.